# How to return Xml rather than JSON from a Web API Action?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

How to configure the actions within a Web API Controller, to return XML rather than JSON?

I have an action which returns a UserProfile object which has XmlElement attributes:

```
[HttpGet]
        public UserProfile SearchByEmail(string siteName, string email)
        {
            var userProfile = this._profileFinderByEmail.Find(siteName, email);

            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return userProfile;
        }
```

When when I run this action, it returns application/json rather than xml. How could I return xml?

Judging by Fiddler the request header that I was sending had the below Accept header key:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

that I expected it to return xml but it doesn't.

How to fix it?

I've also set the below value in the WebApiConfig class:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Viewing from Chrome/Network tab, I can see the below error:

```
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
```

Comment: are you sure , you interfaced your controller to 'ApiController'?

Comment: yes my controller inherits from ApiController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header looks correct, so first you should check if the formatter is there. You can output all the registered formatters with following snippet (you can use it inside of your action method):

```
foreach (var formatter in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", formatter.GetType().Name, String.Join(", ", formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Select(x=>x.MediaType))));
}
```

The results will be visible in *Output* window of *Visual Studio* (set *Show output from* to *Debug*). You should look for line like this:

```
XmlMediaTypeFormatter: application/xml, text/xml
```

If it is not there then it means that it was somehow removed and you need to find that part of code in your application. If it is there then it most probably means that `DataContractSerializer` wasn't able to serialize your entity (you can read more about the supported types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx)).

You also mentioned that you are using `XmlElement` attributes in your entity. By default `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` is using `DataContractSerializer` (as mentioned above) which will ignore those attributes. If you want to switch it to `XmlSerializer` you can use following code (for example in your `Global.asax`):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Of course `XmlSerializer` has its own set of limitations which you need to be aware of.

Comment: thanks. I've seen that XmlMediaTypeFormatter: application/xml, text/xml exists and JSON not. It's also strange that the debugger doesn't break in the global.ascx file.

Comment: @TheLight HTTP error 406 (Not Acceptable) means that no suitable formatter has been found (no formatter for such accept header or formatter is unable to format the entity). You can read more [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation).